# Built in CastOrDefault?

Tags: c#

I get the feeling there is something built in for this. If object is null i'd like the default value (or specifically 0 and I am only using decimal/int). Is there a built in way to write this function?

```
static int GetDecimalFromObject(object o){
    return o==null?0:(decimal)o;
}
```

Comment: You are returning int, but casting to decimal. Strange!!!. Does it compile?

Comment: Are you asking for a generic solution for any return value?

Comment: Would a better question be something along with `static T CastObject<T>(object o){ return o == null ? default(T) : (T)o;`?

Comment: @Tilak It is upgraded. As integer has less precision than decimal it is implicitly cast to decimal. Returning 0M would avoid that.

Comment: oops, typo. I didn't compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Convert.ToDecimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6440ed8.aspx) and [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys.aspx) will return zero if passed null.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use *[`Convert.ToDecimal()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6440ed8.aspx)*

> A decimal number that is equivalent to value, or 0 (zero) if value is
>   null.

Try like this;

```
static decimal GetDecimalFromObject(object o)
{
     return o == null ? Convert.ToDecimal(0) : Convert.ToDecimal(o);
}
```

or more efficient;

```
static decimal  GetDecimalFromObject(object o)
{
    return Convert.ToDecimal(o);
}
```

Comment: you don't need the `?` operator, since `ToDecimal` will return 0 if the argument is `null`

Comment: Now that you're doing nothing but calling another function, there's no need for this function to exist; the caller of this function should just directly call `ToDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `decimal` and `int` data types can't be null, so they would be 0 by default.

If you have a nullable decimal (decimal?) use the `HasValue` method to check if it is null then assign your default of 0.

Comment: but a boxed int/decimal can be null, which is what he has.

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer a different solution:

```
static int GetDecimalFromObject(object o)
{
    return o as int? ?? 0;
}
```

Generic version:

```
static T GetValueFromObject<T>(object o) where T : struct 
{
    return o as T? ?? default(T);
}
```

Note that I've used the `as` operator. If you prefer to throw an exception in case `o` is not of the right type, use the cast operator.

Comment: @BruteCode The cast through `as` will not throw an exception. Using the cast operator will. You can choose.

Comment: I think it will fail if o is `int` and not `int?`. I believe i tried something similar ealier

Comment: @BruteCode No. You can try yourself with `var x = GetDecimalFromObject(42);`. 42 is not an `int?`. The cast to object is implicit but you can add if you want.

Comment: hmm, it worked. I wonder what made it didn't work before. It came from the database. I don't think it was DBNull since i'm sure doing `!= null` fixed it.

Comment: @BruteCode I hope it will be helpful, especially the version with generics.

Answer (score 0):

The ?? Operator might help, but you have to provide the default value:

```
    // y = x, unless x is null, in which case y = -1. 
    int y = x ?? -1;
```

Comment: What is the type of `x` such that you think your sample would compile?

Comment: nullable int. I took the line from the msdn documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: Yes, of course, but the OP was using `object`, not `int?`, so your answer doesn't address the OP's question.